# SciFi story from before 1976 that involves multiple dimensions

Tags: story-identification

Sometime in 1976 I read part of a book and never finished it.

The book or short story involved the following.

Multi-dimensional worlds. Possibly multiple duplicate worlds.
Our world causes conflict by sending things to another dimension, unknowingly causing damage.
The other dimension then retaliates. I remember something about damage to some kind of theater.

Any ideas who the author could be and the work's name?

Comment: Do you remember anything about the characters? Male? Female? Adults? Did the story seem to be aimed at any particular age group? Any memory of the cover? Even the smallest detail may help someone help you.

Answer (score 9):

Oddly enough, I think I just re-read this book as part of a super-nostalgia trip. It sounds like *[The Universe Between](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1417219.The_Universe_Between)* (1965) by Alan E. Nourse.

Due to the damage an experimental 'matter transmitter' is doing to the universe between, the 'Thresholders' go fishing for the device. One miss takes a bite out of a neighborhood including a theater. "The only thing it missed were a couple of small children and the theater cat--"

Comment: I posted the question. Thank you very much. Yes you nailed it. As soon as I read your description I recognized the title and author. Again Thanks