# Book identification - Genius girl through another dimension

Tags: story-identification, books

for the past 2 years atleast, i have been trying to remember the name of a book i read while in high school (so 04-08).

Sadly i have the memory of a goldfish, i can remember the setting and some things that took place, but no names etc.

Starting of the book is about a group of scientists that found a "hole" in our dimension. However you couldnt see it unless you stood at a certain angle and looked a certain way.
They tried sending several scientists through, however all that came back were mentally broken and completely useless. They had the idea, that it is possible the"change" is so big that an older mind could not handle it. So they sent a genius girl (i THINK she was 13-16 at this point) since younger minds can adapt better.

After she goes through she thinks to her self about all the things "wrong" like how her body was in multiple pieces/places, normal thought to move parts did not work as we knew, hands felt purple (felt not looked) and after analyzing things she determined it was much to great a thing to allow those scientists to continue, so she played that it broke her mind as well. Now after having been through the "hole" she can go into it anywhere anytime.

Obviously it continues a lot, i could ramble on, later she ends up as an adult, scientists are at it again, and end up damaging the dimension walls as they use that hole for resource transportation from mars.

Anyone have any idea? lol

Comment: You've already got a load of details, but take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can add anything else and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As user14111 indicated in comments, this is very likely *The Universe Between* (1965) by Alan Nourse, a novel created by combining two shorter works: "[High Threshold](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v47n01_1951-03_Gorgon776#page/n97/mode/2up)" and "[The Universe Between](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v48n01_1951-09_Sam_Hall)" (both published 1951, and both available to read online courtesy of the Internet Archive).

It has been asked about and answered numerous times on the site, so you can look at some of the other questions about it to see if you find matching details:

- [Children's book with "square triangles" in parallel universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33353/childrens-book-with-square-triangles-in-parallel-universe)
- [SciFi story from before 1976 that involves multiple dimensions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41327/scifi-story-from-before-1976-that-involves-multiple-dimensions)
- [Looking for title of book (<1970) about an interdimensional traveler](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135905/looking-for-title-of-book-1970-about-an-interdimensional-traveler)
- [Old sci-fi book - Gail, extreme cold, Jupiter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156947/old-sci-fi-book-gail-extreme-cold-jupiter)

Comment: @user14111 -- After a whole hour, I assumed you'd simply left this one for others to handle. If you would like to put together one of your high-quality responses, by all means do!

Comment: I had actually been on and off looking for the better part of 2 years (i tend to forget things too) but THATS THE BOOK. That is definitely the one i was looking for! You would have thought I'd remember Gails name, but guess not lol.