# Looking for 1960s YA book about portal to parallel universe

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, parallel-universe

I read a 1960s YA/Juvenile novel about a team of scientists working on a portal to another dimension/universe, looking through the portal drives anyone insane. Can't recall author or title, read it in the early 70s, in a school library hardcover binding. I assume from the style it was a 1960s work, it is possible it was from 1950s.

Comment: Maybe ["The Universe Between"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?711) by [Alan E. Nourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_E._Nourse)? It's a book that has come up many times on this site, most recently in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161301/book-identification-genius-girl-through-another-dimension/161315#161315), also see [these questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bstory-identification%5d%20%22universe%20between%22).

Comment: Yes, that looks like the one I remember. Thanks, it was one of those things that has been nagging at my memory!