# What is the name of this book?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read it as a child, a sci-fi book. It started with a government program that discovered an alternate universe, and every person save one went crazy, and could not speak about it. She got pregnant, and took her son into it. He was raised being able to swap between worlds.

After a while, he became employed by the government to use the abilities and he discovered there were other people in this dimension. They started transporting goods, but the shipments sometimes ended in the wrong place. It was because they lacked the mathematics to transport correctly.

Comment: Sounds like [*The Universe Between*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?711) by Alan E. Nourse; for more information see [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161301/book-identification-genius-girl-through-another-dimension). That book was based on short stories called "High Threshold" and "The Universe Between" which you can read for free at the Internet Archive, [here](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v47n01_1951-03_Gorgon776) and [here](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v48n01_1951-09_Sam_Hall). Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @user14111 - Propose this as an answer; I'm morally certain you're right. Whether or not the original poster comes back to confirm it.

Comment: That was it! exactly! I even remember now my grandfather had a subscription to that mag and I avidly read every one when I visited for the summer. I'm reading it again, now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin As the OP has now confirmed it, I can just close this question as a duplicate.